# How to highlight a row if "yes" appears more than once across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a product list export that shows the products and which categories those products are assigned to.

I want to audit the product list by highlight products that are assigned to multiple categories so I am able to quickly scan the sheet for multiple category items.

E.G.
[Product data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmRpx.png)
Column 2,3,5 would be highlighted

I've been trying to set up conditional formatting to highlight the row if yes appears more than 3 times in the row but I can't get my head around the formulas I'm finding on google. The closest I've got so far was `=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(E2:Y2,"Yes")>4)*(E2:Y2<>""))` but it doesn't seem to be very accurate.

The reason its columns `E:Y` is because those are the category columns, there's other product data in columns `A:E`, also this sheet is 20000 products strong so it's a biggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns `E:Y` and apply the following custom formatting formula:

```
=COUNTIF($E1:$Y1,"Yes")>3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I tried something like this to begin with but it never worked. This worked how I wanted it to though so thank you. I expanded the initial selection rage so the whole row would highlight though

Comment: Hi @mickytwotoes,, this will only highlight the row when it has more than 3 Yes and the screen shot U have shared with us,, has not any Row does have has more than 3 Yes !! And U are expecting row 2,3 & 5 to be highlighted only !! BUT below U have twisted the QUESTION "**if yes appears more than 3 times in the row:,,** !!

Comment: @JvdV,,it's okay,,, I was trying to raise the valid issue to OP ,,  his post has lots of discrepancies ,, TITLE differs to the Question Text as well the attached Screen Shot don't have even single row has YES more than  3,, since OP is expecting Row 2,3 & 5 to highlighted,, ☺

Answer (score 1):

*Using one Helper Column solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*I've edited my post because OP has changed the Criteria in last minutes,, earlier was `Highlight row has Yes more than one`,, but now is `Yes more than 3`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell U61 & fill it down:

  `=COUNTIF(R61:U61,"Yes")>3`
- Formula as New Rule:

  `=$U61=TRUE`

**N.B.**

- *For neatness later on you may hide the Helper column.*

[image]

Comment: It could also be useful to name the helper column something more descriptive like "multiple categories". This would help your future self and others know what is going on a little quicker.

Comment: Hi @S.Melted,,, it's a useful suggestion,, will use,,, thanks lot ☺

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but here it goes:
Format a new column in a way that you can count the number of "yes" that you have, for example.

```
**COUNTIF(E2:Y2, "yes")** --> Here you define the range and the word you want to find.
```

Now that you have the "yes" counted and valued, apply conditional formatting to that column with the rule you want to implement:
Go to **Conditional formatting -> New rule -> "Format only cells that contain"** and here you can choose for example,

**"Cell value" - "greater than" - "3"**.